# Creating buffer for polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, buffer

I am quite new to GIS area.
I have a polygon and use concave hull function I could get a boundary like this

[image: example]

What I what to do is add a certain-width band along the boundary, so that it could look like this

[image: desired output]

Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: That's called a "buffer." It should be well documented in the software manual.

Comment: depending on how you've stored your polygon you can use either `gBuffer` from the `rgeos` package or `st_buffer` from the `sf` package.

Comment: Thank you guys! The problem is solved nicely.